# AndroidViewClient openNotification()

Tags: androidviewclient

On my device running Android 4.2.2 the code vc.device.openNotification() does not work, it just flash and close it immediately (of course this same code is working fine on other tested devices). I must install an app "expand Statusbar" and use this code device.startActivity(component='dk.quan.expandstatusbar/.MainActivity') to open the notification bar. Does anybody know a way to open the notification bar via adb, maybe a system package name to open it similar to the app described above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always open the **Notification Bar** by dragging down.

Use `culebra`, then open the **Drag Dialog** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), select the **Start** and **End** point, then **OK** and `culebra` will generate a line similar to this in the script

```
self.device.dragDip((168.0, 17.0), (184.0, 476.0), 1000, 20, 0)
```

which would open the **Notification Bar**.

Comment: Normally it works fine with openNotification() or dragDip, but on this device it looks like any function using the adb input swipe does not work, it just opens the notification bar and closes it very quickly. I guess it should be possible to use the built-in systemUI.apk to open the notification bar, I will try to unpack the app apk described above and try to find the action event used.